# DNN- Best way to provide membership based skins?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am going to develop membership based portal in dotnetnuke.

In the same I want to allow portal manager to define skins for users.

Tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Need more details. It is already possible to set default skins per portal, or do you need to set the skin per portal per user role?

Comment: I want to "set the skin per portal per user role." Is this possible? if yes how?

Answer (score 2):

To change the skin dynamically based upon the user's role, [see this explanation](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/3198/Dynamically-Change-DotNetNuke-Skins-by-Security-Role.aspx), from DotnetNuke.com:

> There are a few different ways to dynamically or programmatically
>   change the skin for a specific page load. DotNetNuke will look first
>   for an override value in the URL. If specific value is found, then DNN
>   will load that skin and/or container on that page load. Second, DNN
>   will look in a local cookie to see if there is a skin being defined.
>   Finally, if the first two methods did not specify a skin to load, DNN
>   will load the default skins defined by the page or site. In the event
>   that the skin doesn’t exist, the default skin that ships with DNN will
>   be loaded.
>
> This is why it’s important to not delete the original skin package
>   after installing.
>
> Probably the best way to approach dynamically loading a skin based on
>   security role would be to create a simple cookie using either a
>   DotNetNuke module, or HttpModule. Either way, you will be able to
>   retrieve the user information, and based on the IsInSecurityRole()
>   property, generate a cookie that will in effect load the desired skin.

In Essence, in a DotNetNuke Module placed on every page, you will have to check the following:

1. Which portal is the user in?
2. Which security role is the user in?
3. Based upon 1 & 2, which skin should the user see?

If the answer to #3 is "a non-default skin", then you will need to execute some code like this, taken from DotNetNuke.com:

```
'import DotNetNuke.Entities.Users'
If Not Me.UserInfo Is Nothing AndAlso Me.UserInfo.UserID > Null.NullInteger Then
  If Me.UserInfo.IsInRole("My Security Role") Then
    ' import System.Web.HttpCookie 
    Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("SkinSrc", "[G]Skins/DarkKnight/Home-Mega-Menu.ascx"))
  Else
      ' either assign another skin, or do nothing 
  End If
Else
  ' either assign another skin, or do nothing 
End If
```

The above code snipped shows how to set the skin by adding a cookie key-value-pair.

I'd probably put the above logic into a DNN module that is invisible and is automatically added to all pages on the site; otherwise, you can probably inject the logic into Default.aspx (not recommended due to editing DNN core).

Note: PortalID is a field that is accessible in each module project. `Response.Write("My Portal ID: " & PortalID.ToString())`